Creating a Daisy UI Menu in VueJS?
Has anyone ever used daisy ui in vue js? I was working on vite+vuetify project and I have just installed DaisyUI I have a pretty complex menu and I am wondering what do I need to do in order to make it work. The vue components do pick up some classes while some are not picked.
Do I need to completely remove vuetify from my project?
If I remove vuetify how will it effect my project?
Below is my current app bar consisting of vue components
<template>
  <div>
    <v-app-bar class="navbar bg-primary text-primary-content">
      <v-row align="center">
        <v-col cols="4">
          <v-toolbar-title>Verus Currency Explorer</v-toolbar-title>
        </v-col>

        <v-col cols="4" class="text-center">
          <v-toolbar-title>RPC: {{ rpcValue }} Verison: {{ versionInfo }}</v-toolbar-title>
        </v-col>

  <v-col cols="4" class="text-right">
    <v-menu>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
        <v-btn
          color="white"
          v-bind="props"
          class="btn btn-ghost text-xl">
          <v-icon>mdi-menu</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </template>
      <div class="dropdown">
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item>
          <router-link to="/" class="nav-link" :class="{ 'active-menu': $route.path === '/' }">Dashboard</router-link>
         </v-list-item>
         <v-list-item>
          <router-link to="/currencies" class="nav-link" :class="{ 'active-menu': $route.path === '/currencies' }">Currencies</router-link>
         </v-list-item>
         <v-list-item>
          <router-link to="/settings" class="nav-link" :class="{ 'active-menu': $route.path === '/settings' }">Settings</router-link>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list> 
      </div>
    </v-menu>
    <v-btn class="btn btn-ghost text-xl">
      <router-link to="/login" class="nav-link">
        <v-icon>mdi-login</v-icon>
        </router-link>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn icon class="hidden-sm-and-up" @click="drawer = !drawer">
            <v-icon>mdi-menu</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
    </v-app-bar>


    <v-navigation-drawer :model-value="drawer" temporary class="dropdown" :icon="menubar">
      <v-list>
        <router-link to="/" class="nav-link" :class="{ 'active-menu': $route.path === '/' }">
          <v-list-item>
            <v-icon>mdi-view-dashboard</v-icon>
            Dashboard
          </v-list-item>
        </router-link>
        <router-link to="/currencies" class="nav-link" :class="{ 'active-menu': $route.path === '/currencies' }">
          <v-list-item>
            <v-icon>mdi-currency-usd</v-icon>
            Currencies
          </v-list-item>
        </router-link>
        <router-link to="/settings" class="nav-link" :class="{ 'active-menu': $route.path === '/settings' }">
          <v-list-item>
            <v-icon>mdi-cog</v-icon>
            Settings
          </v-list-item>
        </router-link>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>

  </div>
</template>


